# problems using string split python

Tags: python, django, string, split

I'm using Django so all of this runs in a virtual environment so this might be the cause of my problem (even if I don't know how)

I created a function to split a string containing date and time:

```
def split_time(time_string, string):  # '2018-03-17T05:20:00+01:00'
    if string == 'date':
        date = time_string.split('T')[0]
        return date
    elif string == 'time':
        pre_time = time_string.split('T')[-1]
        time = pre_time.split('+')[0]
        return time
```

the comment displays what string I get

I use `[0]` and `[-1]` because for some reason the the array fills up in the negative direction (I already created a question because of that which gave me the workaround of using `[-1]`, if needed I will link the question)

here I call the function:

```
    end_event_time = split_time(end, 'time')
    test = end_event_time.split(':')
    h = test[0]
    m = test[1]
    print(end_event_time, h, m)
```

test  displays `['05', '20', '00']`

`h` gives me `05` while `m` raises the error `list index out of range`

`[-1]` displays `00`

My problem is that not only do I need to call the variables with negative indexes, I can only access the first and the last variable

I´m using the Django environment but these tests are displayed on the console

Any help would be appreciated!

**edit**

includes:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import datetime
```

The full function looks like this:

```
def is_double(start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
    start_date_time = start_date +'T'+ start_time +":00+02:00"
    print("testing:", start_date_time )
    end_date_time = end_date +'T'+ end_time      +":00+02:00"              
    start_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' 
    #Getting the upcoming 20 events
    eventsResult = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=start_now, maxResults=20, singleEvents=True,
    orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])
    if not events:
        print('no event')
        return False
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
    #up to this line everything is copied from the google api website
    #i am getting the 10 upcoming events from a google calendar
        end_event_time = split_time(end, 'time')
        test = end_event_time.split(':')
        h = test[0]
        m = test[-1]
        print(end_event_time,test, h, m)
  return true
```

Output:

```
05:20:00 ['05', '20', '00'] 05 00
01:03:00 ['01', '03', '00'] 01 00
```

Note: To test this a connection to the google calendar is needed but I get the same output if I use `end_event_time = '05:20:00'` instead of my split_time() so I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the calendar API.

Comment: what you are trying to do is probably the wrong attempt in the first place. Do not store datetime values as strings and split them but rather work with the normal date time object. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378

Comment: You may be wrong in something else. if you have the list `['05', '20', '00']`, this is not possible to get index error on index `1`

Comment: @hansTheFranz can i check wether the values i get are date time objects? as far as i know the google api returns strings but i could be wrong

Comment: @hansTheFranz i just checked using


        `end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
        if isinstance(end, datetime.datetime): print('YES')
        else: print('NO') `


it displayed NO so i recieve a string from the calendar api

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, a friend solved it:

I tried calling `test[1]` but test is a list!

So using push and pop fixed it!